# How to search and replace tag and attribute value in xml using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I want to search `tag/child` value in XML file and replace/update value with new value and save changes to same XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) from Python standard library.